# How to typeset pictures like in picture?

Tags: picture-mode

[image]

I just want to typeset pictures like in picture, one in left and one in right,and the right one is slightly lower than the left one.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show us what you've tried so far. Please also tell us if you need to employ a specific LaTeX document class and/or other formatting requirements.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Wouldn't these be QR Codes? There are packages to produce them here: [QR Code](https://www.ctan.org/topic/qrcode)

Comment: Interestingly, floatrow uses a picture environment internally to arrange subfigures.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking for how to position the images and text you could try a tikz matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\begin{document}


\section{some caption}

some text

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=4cm, row sep=-1.5cm,
            nodes={align=left}]{
        \node {\includegraphics{qr.png} \\ Text A}; & \\
            & \node {\includegraphics{qr.png} \\ Text B};\\
        \node {\includegraphics{qr.png} \\ Text C}; & \\
            & \node {\includegraphics{qr.png} \\ Text D};\\
        \node {\includegraphics{qr.png} \\ Text E}; & \\
            & \node {\includegraphics{qr.png} \\ Text F};\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Note though that to be able to place the text on a new line with the image inside the node it must be aligned left, so you wouldn't get centred text with this method. But in any case, the output looks something like this:

[image: image matrix]